# Analytic solutions to $f(5 x + x^3) = f(5 x) + f(3 x)$?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, polynomials, dynamical-systems, functional-equations

I was wondering about real-analytic solutions to the equation

$$f(5 x + x^3) = f(5 x) + f(3 x)$$

If I plug in $x=0$ it follows $f(0)=0$. Also $f(-x) = -f(x)$.

My initial guess was a sum of arcsines but that seems a bad idea ? afterall the $x^3$ part is "inside" and not "outside " ( outside like f(x)^3 ...).

My second guess was a sum of cube roots, but that also seems like a bad idea ?

My third guess was to rewrite it as an integral but I got stuck trying.

My 4 th idea was to use a helping (Abel) equation : $ g(5x + x^3) = g(x) + 1 $ and express $f$ in terms of $g$.

We could also compute the taylor coefficients from the equations but Im not sure if that gives insight ?

Is $f$ a hypergeometric function ??

What are good asymptotics for $f$ ?

I have strong arguments that $f$ is not entire.
unless ofcourse $f(x) = 0$. Notice if $a(x)$ is a solution then $C a(x)$ is also one for a real constant $C$.

And how about $C^{oo}$ solutions that are nowhere analytic ? Does that even make sense ?

Would it help to take the derivative on both sides ?

Is there a nonzero elementary solution ?

Is the solution unique up to a constant multiple ?

Is this related to fractals ? How about addition formula's ?

And how would it look on the complex plane ?

Comment: Write it in terms of series because it is analytic. And find recurrence relation on the coefficiento of that serie

Comment: @EDX how do you know such a recurrence relation exists ? Are you saying it must be hypergeometric ?

Comment: I wanted to post a second question with $f(5 x + x^3) = f(2 x) + f(3x)$ but it was denied as being duplicate of this one.

Comment: A somewhat similar question : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/209227/find-a-non-constant-real-analytic-function-fx-such-that-for-x-in-bbb-r-f

Answer (score 4):

When there is an analytic solution $f(x)\not\equiv0$ there is an integer $r\geq0$ and an analytic $g$ with
$$f(x)=x^r \>g(x),\quad g(0)\ne0\ .$$
Your functional equation then implies
$$x^r(5+x^2)^r g(5x+x^3)\equiv (5x)^r g(5x)+(3x)^r g(3x)\ ,$$
so that after division by $x^r$ we obtain
$$(5+x^2)^r g(5x+x^3)\equiv 5^r g(5x)+3^r g(3x)\ .$$
Putting $x=0$ here gives
$$5^r g(0)=(5^r+3^r) g(0)\ ,$$
which is not compatible with $g(0)\ne0$.

Comment: Also very intresting. +1  I think you reached the same conclusion as the other answer from H.H. Rugh : the function is not analytic at 0.

Comment: What fascinates me is that $r$ does not even need to be an integer. SO this singularity at 0 should be very " bad " .

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't quite look like you may find a solution which is real-analytic at zero. Otherwise you would have a power-series $f(x) = cx^n + O(x^{n+1})$ with non-zero $c$ which yields $c (5^n - 5^n - 3^n) = 0$. But you could, of course, adjust the constants a bit...

Comment: Hmm intresting. +1  If we change one five to a two , it might be analytic at zero. But would it grow at a similar speed ??

Comment: Yes, $f(5x+x^3) = f(2x) + f(3x)$ does have a solution which is analytic at zero (unique up to a multiplicative constant). But the proof that I would concoct is quite involved. It uses so-called transfer operators and the Ruelle-Perron-Frobenius theorem.

Comment: Care to explain more about that last comment H.H. Rugh ? I do not know Ruelle-Perron-Frobenius well. I do not even see the connection after I looked it up. Seems intresting but I do not get it to be honest.

Comment: @mick The idea is to get $f$ as a fixed point (eigenvector) of a linear operator. Writing $y=5x+x^3$ you may solve in a ngh of 0, to get $x=\frac{1}{5}\psi(y) = y/5+O(y^3)$. Then $f(y) = Lf(y)$ where $L$ is the linear operator $Lf(y)= f(2/5 \psi(y)) + f(3/5 \psi(y))$, a sum of two compositions with contracting maps (which is where the transfer operator enters into the picture). On a space of analytic functions at zero it has eigenvalues $\lambda_n=(2/5)^n+(3/5)^n$, $n=0,1,...$. For $n=1$ the eigenvalue is 1 and the eigenfunction is the wanted function. In fact, the RPF theorem is not needed.